# Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, spring, servlets, classnotfoundexception

I've had a problem with my RESTApi service in JAVA. I'm a newbie in this language and answers in other topics doesn't seem to work for me.

I added 2 external libs to my project and I think the problem is there.

My pom.xml file looks like this:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>org.Test</groupId>
<artifactId>Webservice</artifactId>
<version>0.1.0</version>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.2</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.7.RELEASE</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>de.signotec</groupId>
        <artifactId>STPadLib</artifactId>
        <version>8.17.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>de.signotec</groupId>
        <artifactId>STPad-native</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.23.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

The controller:

```
@RestController
public class InputController {

private final SignopadService service;

public InputController(){
    this.service = new SignopadService();
}

@PostMapping("/inputTest")
public String create(@RequestBody String json){
    return "CustomerId : " + this.service.TestReturn(json);
}
}
```

Service:

```
public class SignopadService {

private Gson gson; 
private SignopadCore signopadCore;

public int TestReturn(String json){
    gson = new Gson();
    RequestModel requestObj = gson.fromJson(json, RequestModel.class);

    try{
        signopadCore = new SignopadCore(requestObj);
    }catch (SigPadApiException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return requestObj.customerId;
}
```

}

And when I try to execute `signopadCore = new SignopadCore(requestObj)`
I am getting this error.

SignopadCore class (constructor):

```
 public SignopadCore(RequestModel model) throws SigPadApiException{
    this.requestType = RequestTypeEnum.values()[model.requestType];

    if(!apiInit){ 
        this.connectionModel = model.connectionModel;
        initializeAPI();
        getDevices(connectionModel);
        createButtons();
    }
    createPage();
}
```

Someone can help me with this problem?

EDIT:
Full stack trace:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jna.Callback
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
at de.signotec.STPad.api.SigPadFacade.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[STPadLib-8.17.0.jar:8.17.0]
at de.signotec.STPad.api.SigPadFacade.getInstance(Unknown Source) ~[STPadLib-8.17.0.jar:8.17.0]
at org.Test.signopad.SignopadCore.<clinit>(SignopadCore.java:29) ~[classes/:na]
at org.Test.webservice.SignopadService.TestReturn(SignopadService.java:27) ~[classes/:na]
at org.Test.webservice.InputController.create(InputController.java:35) ~[classes/:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:209) ~[spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136) ~[spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:877) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:783) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:974) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:877) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:851) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:496) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1468) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_181]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_181]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_181]
```

EDIT 2:

I was added the jna reference and now i have problem 'cause of  `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library 'STPadJava'`

From Signotec documentation I have

> In Windows, stpad-native.jar is required in the classpath when using the SigPadFacade.  The native library it contains is automatically loaded with JNA. Alternatively, the .dll file can be extracted from the stpad-native.jar and its location set with the System.property jna.library.path when starting the application. All other .dll and .manifest files, which have been included in the version 8.0.22 and earlier, are no longer required.

When I running application I see in System.getProperties() that I have the path to stpad-native.jar. This is my property java.calss.path:

```
java.class.path => C:\FitxWS\Webservice\target\classes;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-web\2.0.3.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-web-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter\2.0.3.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot\2.0.3.RELEASE\spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-autoconfigure\2.0.3.RELEASE\spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-logging\2.0.3.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-logging-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-classic\1.2.3\logback-classic-1.2.3.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-core\1.2.3\logback-core-1.2.3.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-to-slf4j\2.10.0\log4j-to-slf4j-2.10.0.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-api\2.10.0\log4j-api-2.10.0.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\jul-to-slf4j\1.7.25\jul-to-slf4j-1.7.25.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\javax\annotation\javax.annotation-api\1.3.2\javax.annotation-api-1.3.2.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\org\yaml\snakeyaml\1.19\snakeyaml-1.19.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-json\2.0.3.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-json-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-databind\2.9.6\jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-annotations\2.9.0\jackson-annotations-2.9.0.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-core\2.9.6\jackson-core-2.9.6.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\datatype\jackson-datatype-jdk8\2.9.6\jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.9.6.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\datatype\jackson-datatype-jsr310\2.9.6\jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.9.6.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\module\jackson-module-parameter-names\2.9.6\jackson-module-parameter-names-2.9.6.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-tomcat\2.0.3.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-tomcat-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-core\8.5.31\tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-el\8.5.31\tomcat-embed-el-8.5.31.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-websocket\8.5.31\tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.31.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\validator\hibernate-validator\6.0.10.Final\hibernate-validator-6.0.10.Final.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\javax\validation\validation-api\2.0.1.Final\validation-api-2.0.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\org\jboss\logging\jboss-logging\3.3.2.Final\jboss-logging-3.3.2.Final.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\classmate\1.3.4\classmate-1.3.4.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-webmvc\5.0.7.RELEASE\spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aop\5.0.7.RELEASE\spring-aop-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-context\5.0.7.RELEASE\spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-expression\5.0.7.RELEASE\spring-expression-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-core\5.0.7.RELEASE\spring-core-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jcl\5.0.7.RELEASE\spring-jcl-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\1.7.25\slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\com\google\code\gson\gson\2.8.2\gson-2.8.2.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-web\5.0.7.RELEASE\spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-beans\5.0.7.RELEASE\spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\de\signotec\STPadLib\8.17.0\STPadLib-8.17.0.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\de\signotec\STPad-native\8.0.23.1\STPad-native-8.0.23.1.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\com\sun\jna\jna\3.0.9\jna-3.0.9.jar
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please include the full exception stacktrace in your question

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Here you are

Comment: The error indicates that JNA is not on the classpath. It would seem that your STPad dependency doesn't correctly specify its dependencies on JNA. You'll need to add a dependency on JNA yourself.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Any suggestion how I can resolve this issue?

Comment: _"You'll need to add a dependency on JNA yourself."_ See also https://github.com/java-native-access/jna. For example https://search.maven.org/artifact/net.java.dev.jna/jna/4.5.2/jar

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I edited my question. Maybe you could help me?

Comment: I'd start with following the debugging suggested in the [JNA FAQ](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/blob/master/www/FrequentlyAskedQuestions.md#calling-nativeload-causes-an-unsatisfiedlinkerror). This could be something like running 64 bit Java, while there is only a 32 bit DLL, or maybe something more complicated. If you can't find the problem yourself, make sure to add the JNA debug logging to your question.